# Java - NodeList capacity

Tags: java, xpath, size, nodelist, capacity

I´m filling a nodelist from a xml file using the following code:

`final Document listDoc = docBuilder.parse(makeInputSource(listQuery.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
final XPath listXpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
final NodeList cycles = (NodeList)listXpath.compile("Entities/Entity/Fields").evaluate(listDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);`

so everythings goes well, but my xml has 153 records, the nodelist is only capturing 100, I read that the initial capacity of a nodelist is 100, so I need to increase that capacity to fit the 153 entries the xml has.

my questions, supposedly the capacity of the nodelist should increase itself to meet the number of records read from the xml, is that true? if it is, any ideas why is not acting that way?, if is not, how to increase the capacity of the nodelist?

Comment: Where did you read that?  I've never seen such a restriction.  I just ran a quick test, and had no problem selecting 153 nodes using an XPath.

Comment: I read that from this page https://www.norsys.com/netica-j/docs/javadocs/norsys/netica/NodeList.html

Comment: how I understand is not a restriction is just the initial capacity of the nodelist, it should be growing in proportion with the added objects,  but is not doing it

Comment: I don't know what a norsys.netica.NodeList is.  My assumption was that you were using standard Java objects.  If you're using javax.xml.xpath.XPath, you will expect it to return an org.w3c.dom.NodeList.  Maybe you could provide enough of your code to reproduce the error, we could figure out where you're going wrong.

Comment: apparently I was looking at the wrong direction the problem was the XML I was trying to read, instead of my code. the XML is generated by a server through an html request this part is the one that is failing,

thanks for the help